# JQuery html table search by many attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to search by three attributes on each row.

I am able to search by one attribute, like this:

```
var rows = $("#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=1]");
```

But this throws error:

```
var rows = $("#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=1,cLastN=2]");
```

How to search by all three attributes?

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  debugger;
  var rows = $("#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=1]");    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl1' >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr cName='1' cLastN='2' cMiddleN='3'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
      <tr cName='2' cLastN='2' cMiddleN='4'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
      <tr cName='5' cLastN='7' cMiddleN='3'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </tbody>
  
  
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<button id="btn1">Search</button>
```

Comment: Try `var rows = $("#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=1][cLastN=2][cMiddleN=xxx]");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.You need to include the attribute selectors separately, depending on your requirement. If you want to select any element with either attribute (ie. OR logic) use this:

```
var rows = $('#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName="1"], #tbl1 > tbody > tr[cLastN="2"]');
```

Whereas if you want elements with both attributes (ie. AND), use this:

```
var rows = $('#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName="1"][cLastN="2"]');
```

Also be aware that you're using completely non-standard attributes which can cause issues with JS. I'd suggest changing them to `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you have any good link with explanations on this?

Comment: It's all in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I use non-standard attributes quite often. Perhaps you have link to explanation why data-* should be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use commas (,) to perfom OR selectors

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  debugger;
  var rows = $("#tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=1]  , #tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=2], #tbl1 > tbody > tr[cName=3]"); 
  console.log(rows)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl1' >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr cName='1' cLastN='2' cMiddleN='3'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
      <tr cName='2' cLastN='2' cMiddleN='4'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
      <tr cName='5' cLastN='7' cMiddleN='3'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </tbody>
  
  
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<button id="btn1">Search</button>
```

Comment: @Phylogenesis yep spotted that as soon as i saved, fixed now